# Android AsyncTask

Tags: android-asynctask

Saludos comunidad. Estoy en un problema. Empezare diciendo que no se siquiera si estoy en la categoría aficionado. De todas maneras y con muchísimo esfuerzo he logrado algunos avances, pero estoy atascado.
App para reproducir un video en un dispositivo. Ese video lo disparo haciendo play desde otro lugar (via UDP implementado con ESP8266).
Hasta el play, llegue. Pero necesito disparar Pausa y Stop. No lo he logrado despues de varios dias.
Codigo:

```
public class DemoActivity extends AppCompatActivity
package com.helap.player360;
{
public static final String sPath = "file://mnt/sdcard/vr/";
private String u;
private UDPUtils udpUtils;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_demo);
    udpUtils = new UDPUtils(this);
    udpUtils.startReceiveUdp();

    final EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text_url);

    SparseArray<String> data = new SparseArray<>();

    data.put(data.size(), sPath + "XXX.mp4");

    {
        @Override
        public void onSpinnerClicked(int index, int key, String value)
        {
            et.setText(value);
            u = value;
        }
    }).init(R.id.spinner_url);

    findViewById(R.id.sync_button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            //MD360PlayerActivity.startVideo(DemoActivity.this, Uri.parse(u));
            SendMessage("192.168.0.25", "SYNC");
        }
    });
}
```

Este bloque funciona bien, sin problemas. Ahora la clase interface, la siguiente, que tambien funciona.

```
package com.helap.player360;
public class UDPUtils implements AsyncResponse
{
   private UDPServer udpServer;
   private UDPSender udpSender;
   private DemoActivity context;
   public int modo;
   public UDPUtils(Context context){this.context=(DemoActivit)context;}

  @Override
  public void processFinish(final String output)
  {
      context.runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
      {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            if(output.equals("200"))
            {
                context.sync();
            }
            if(output.equals("300"))
            {
                context.start();
            }
            if(output.equals("400"))
            {
                modo = 3;
                //context.pausa();

            }
        }
    });
}

/** Start UDP server as asynctask **/
void startReceiveUdp()
{
    if (udpServer == null)
    {
        udpServer = new UDPServer();
        udpServer.setPort(8888);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
        {
            udpServer.delegate = this;
            udpServer.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
        }
        else
        {
            udpServer.execute();
        }
    }
}

interface AsyncResponse
{
    void processFinish(String output);
}
```

Una clase que entiendo es interface entre la iniciual y la ppal

```
public abstract class MD360PlayerActivity extends Activity
{

    private static final SparseArray<String> sDisplayMode = new SparseArray<>();
    private static final SparseArray<String> sInteractiveMode = new SparseArray<>();
    private static final SparseArray<String> sProjectionMode = new SparseArray<>();
private static final SparseArray<String> sAntiDistortion = new SparseArray<>();
private static final SparseArray<String> sPitchFilter = new SparseArray<>();
private static final SparseArray<String> sFlingEnabled = new SparseArray<>();
int m, n;
static
{
}

public static void startVideo(Context context, Uri uri)
{
    start(context, uri, VideoPlayerActivity.class);
}

private static void start(Context context, Uri uri, Class < ? extends Activity > clz)
{
    Intent i = new Intent(context, clz);
    i.setData(uri);
    context.startActivity(i);
}
public void cancelBusy(){findViewById(R.id.progress).setVisibility(View.GONE);}

//*******************************************************************************
private XXXLibrary mXXLibrary;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
 ........
}

abstract protected XXXLibrary createXXXLibrary();

public MDVRLibrary getVRLibrary() {return mVRLibrary;}

@Override
protected void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    mVRLibrary.onResume(this);
}

@Override
protected void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    mVRLibrary.onPause(this);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy()
{
    super.onDestroy();
    mVRLibrary.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
{
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    mVRLibrary.onOrientationChanged(this);
}

protected Uri getUri()
{
    Intent i = getIntent();
    if (i == null || i.getData() == null)
      {
        return null;
      }
    return i.getData();
   }
}
```

Y por ultimo la clase sobre la que no puedo actuar.

```
package com.helap.player360;
import...
public class VideoPlayerActivity extends MD360PlayerActivity
{
private MediaPlayerWrapper mMediaPlayerWrapper = new   MediaPlayerWrapper();
private int d;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    mMediaPlayerWrapper.init();
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mMediaPlayerWrapper.setPreparedListener(new IMediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(IMediaPlayer mp)
        {
            cancelBusy();
            if (getVRLibrary() != null)
            {
                getVRLibrary().notifyPlayerChanged();
            }
        }
    });

    mMediaPlayerWrapper.getPlayer().setOnErrorListener(new IMediaPlayer.OnErrorListener()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onError(IMediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra)
        {
            String error = String.format("Play Error what=%d extra=%d", what, extra);
            Toast.makeText(VideoPlayerActivity.this, error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }
    });

    mMediaPlayerWrapper.getPlayer().setOnVideoSizeChangedListener(new IMediaPlayer.OnVideoSizeChangedListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onVideoSizeChanged(IMediaPlayer mp, int width, int height, int sar_num, int sar_den)
        {
            getVRLibrary().onTextureResize(width, height);
        }
    });
 /********************************************************/
    Uri uri = getUri();
    if (uri != null)
    {
        mMediaPlayerWrapper.openRemoteFile(uri.toString());
        mMediaPlayerWrapper.prepare();
    }

    findViewById(R.id.pause).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            mMediaPlayerWrapper.pause();
        }
    });
    findViewById(R.id.button_resume).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            mMediaPlayerWrapper.resume();
        }
    });
}
//**********************************

@Override
protected void onDestroy()
{
    super.onDestroy();
    mMediaPlayerWrapper.destroy();
}

@Override
protected  void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    mMediaPlayerWrapper.pause();
}

@Override
protected void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    mMediaPlayerWrapper.resume();
   }
}
```

En estas ultimas tres (protected void onDestroy(), protected  void onPause(), protected void onResume())son son sobre las que quiero actuar via UDP con una AsyncTask, y la verdad, no lo he logrado.
Cualquier ayuda, sera agradecida eternamente.

Comment: Has logrado enviar y recibir datos? primero parte por eso. Usa [Log](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat.html) para escribir los datos en la salida de android studio y ver si recibes algo o no (envia codigos de instrucciones para play, stop y pause de forma que puedas diferenciarlos dentro de tu app). Luego usa esos datos para generar instrucciones en tu componente de video.

Comment: Bienvenido! tu pregunta luce muy bien.. solo te recomiendo que leas [ask] y [tour] para que sepas como funcionamos.

Comment: Si he logrado enviar y recibir. De hecho sincronizo los dispositivos con un comando SYNC. Mi problema es cuando corre el video. no se como ni por donde entrar y hacer pausa en esa clase. lo logro con un boton, pero no desde el exterior